# how to use slider as progress bar and control audio in kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, android-music-player

> **I am making a music player for android and now I am successful to play and pause the song but the
> problem is that as in other music player app like Spotify or Google Play Music we have a slider 
>  at the bottom and we can use that slider to control the currently playing song 
> So the point is that want to do the same and I want to add a slider which also work like a** ***PROGRESS BAR***
> **and we can use that progress bar to control the song playing I tried this and ended up with this code -:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.slider import MDSlider


class MusicApp(MDApp):

   def build(self):

          a = mixer.Sound(filename)
         
          slider = MDSlider(min=0,max=total_length,value = 0, 
                            pos_hint={'center_x':0.50,'center_y':0.6},  
                            size_hint=(0.6,0.1))

           screen = Screen()

           screen.add_widget(slider)
           return screen

MusicApp().run()
```

> **Can anyone help me out with this 
>
> Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a slider as both a progress bar and a controller. Here is some code (based on your code) that does it:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.slider import MDSlider


class MySlider(MDSlider):
    sound = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current == self:
            # call super method and save its return
            ret_val = super(MySlider, self).on_touch_up(touch)

            # adjust position of sound
            self.sound.seek(self.max * self.value_normalized)

            # if sound is stopped, restart it
            if self.sound.state == 'stop':
                MDApp.get_running_app().start_play()

            # return the saved return value
            return ret_val
        else:
            return super(MySlider, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class MusicApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.a = SoundLoader.load('test.mp3')

        # create slider and pass the sound to it
        self.slider = MySlider(min=0, max=self.a.length, value=0, sound=self.a,
                          pos_hint={'center_x': 0.50, 'center_y': 0.6},
                          size_hint=(0.6, 0.1))

        screen = Screen()

        screen.add_widget(self.slider)

        self.updater = None

        # start the sound
        self.start_play()

        return screen

    def start_play(self, *args):
        # play the sound
        self.a.play()

        if self.updater is None:
            # schedule updates to the slider
            self.updater = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_slider, 0.5)

    def update_slider(self, dt):
        # update slider
        self.slider.value = self.a.get_pos()

        # if the sound has finished, stop the updating
        if self.a.state == 'stop':
            self.updater.cancel()
            self.updater = None


MusicApp().run()
```

the `MySlider` class extends `MDSlider` and over-rides its `on_touch_up()` method to adjust the sound position. It is also updated by  scheduled `update_slider()` method.