# MDSlider Bug in KivyMD - on_touch_up gets fired when clicked on the screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, slider, kivymd

I am facing a problem, where I want to get the value of the MDslider in KivyMD using the `on_touch_up()` method, it works but the problem is even when I click/touch anywhere on the `screen` apart from the MDSlider the `on_touch_up()` method gets fired.

And when I click/touch on the MDSlider the method gets fired twice

#### Code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder, builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.slider import MDSlider
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout


class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.slider = MDSlider(
            min=0,
            max=100,
            size_hint=(0.4,0.1),
            pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        )
        self.slider.bind(on_touch_up = self.get_slider_value)
        self.add_widget(self.slider)

    def get_slider_value(self, obj, obj_prop):
        print(obj.value)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

> Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a bug, it is the designed behavior. All `Widgets` get the `on_touch_up` event. You must use the `collide_point(*touch.pos)` method to determine if the touch is on your `Slider`. However, the `on_touch_up()` being fired twice does seem like a bug. Consider using:

```
self.slider.bind(value = self.get_slider_value)
```

instead of `on_touch_up`.

To use `collide_point()` in the `get_slider_value()` (if you bind to `on_touch_up`) try something like:

```
def get_slider_value(self, slider, touch):
    if slider.collide_point(*touch.pos):
        print(slider.value)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but can you show me how you can use collide_point(*touch.pos) in this scenario? I referred to you answer on this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63882665/how-to-use-slider-as-progress-bar-and-control-audio-in-kivy-python] but wasn't able to do much with that. Also thanks a lot for the quick help